# Which is better form of writing javascript code?

Tags: javascript

I am studying JS from freecodecamp and the instructor was making an app which counts people, and he had written the code like this:

```
let countEl = document.getElementById("count-el")
console.log(countEl)

function increment() {
  count = count + 1
  countEl.innerText = count

}

increment()
```

can i write it  like this

```
let count = 0

function increment() {
  count = count + 1
  document.getElementById("count-el").innerText = count

}

increment()
```

where i dont have to define  countEl  separately .

Comment: either is good, former won't work if it's above that element, though is a microsecond "faster" (don't worry about that)

Comment: How do you know it is faster  and why it wont work?

Comment: Second is better but only because `count` is properly declared. Other than that, it basically doesn't matter.

Comment: First one throws an error because `count` is not defined.

Comment: count is defined in above code ...typo

Comment: It is good idea to use local variable when you can. Global variable can raise unexpected error...

Comment: I do know `document.getElementById("count-el")` takes more time than not doing it - first code you do it once, second code you do it more than once - anyway, that was a stupid comment, the time is measured in microseconds, no effect.... as for not work ... I said **IF** that code is above the target element it will fail

Comment: Thankyou to all of you guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second snippet is definitely better. The first one is a no-go for several reasons:

- the `countEl` variable is global, which makes the function fragile and impossible to test
- resource acquisition is separated from the actual usage and there's no apparent connection between both
- should the HTML element go away for some reason, the reference will be kept around, thus creating a memory leak

On a more general note, try to design your code to avoid globals altogether and to only request resources when they are actually needed and free them as soon as possible.